# Add user input directly to index.html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to allow users to upload images to my site through a direct link. I have tried php but with my free host it will not work. I was wondering if there was a way I could use a form and take the user's input and put it directly into the site's code. 
This is my current code and it would be perfect it I could just toss it right above this

```
    <img src="bar.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="com3.png" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="image6.jpeg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="image3.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="image4.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="image7.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="20151106_141823.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="erik.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="1.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="2.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="3.jpg" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="4.png" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="5.png" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="6.png" height="400" width="400">
    <img src="7.jpg" height="400" width="400">
```

I have those images that I put in manually but I want people to upload them and use a direct link from some where like imgur and then it re sizes to 400x400 and is put at the top of the feed

Comment: Find another free host that support PHP. This can't be done with just html.

Comment: Nope, won't work. You can send the image to the server using a form, but the server needs php/asp.net to save the file and show it on the page.

Comment: So there is not way to do this with js?

Comment: you will be having database interface with your free hosting. you and insert base code of image directely to data base and while showing get it from db.

Comment: @RyanDockman of course, JS on the server can do this. But that means you need NodeJS. JavaScript in browser can not touch what is on the server. I doubt that a free hosting will be running NodeJS.